# ASP.NET MVC 4 Open Bootstrap modal with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to open modal in specific path using asp.net mvc 4 + jquery, heres the code:

Card.cshtml

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary openModal" data-path="/Client/Edit/@Model.ClientID">Editar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary openModal" data-path="/Client/Products/@Model.ClientID">Products</button>
</div>
```

then in modal.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.openModal', function () {
    var path = $(this).attr("data-path");
    $("#modal").load(path, function () {
        $("#modal").modal();
    })
});
```

in ClientController

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
{
    Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);

    if (client == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(client);
}

public ActionResult Products(long clientID)
{
    return View(db.Products.Where(p => p.ClientID == clientID).ToList());
}
```

The Edit action works, but the Products action not (i put a breakpoint and its not called). Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you check the response, is there any error?

Comment: The browser just "fade" like when "Edit" Modal open, but not happen, the controller's "Products Action" is not called, but cheking on chrome the "path" property of jquery code is right

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the name of parameter

```
public ActionResult Products(long clientID)
{
    return View(db.Products.Where(p => p.ClientID == clientID).ToList());
}
```

Changed from clientID to just id and works. It's because default routes is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```